# How to select and edit a shape and use Arabic Characters in Flash CS5 Professional V11.0?

Tags: flash, text, selection, flash-cs5, arabic

I use Flash CS5 Professional V11.0 to edit some mistakes in a short flash movie about certain company contact information.

The Flash contains many shapes and every shape has the following data about each branch:-
Branch Name - Manager Name - Address - Telephone - Fax - Mobile - Email.

These data is written in Arabic and stored as Shapes(Images) and I would like to edit the characters and numbers written to the correct ones.

I want to select the wrong characters and replace them or clear them and write the correct characters but I can not write Arabic in Flash to do that although Arabic is installed well and worked ok in other appliactions like Word and Excel.

Treating Text as Images and Shapes is a difficult and boring task.

I had a rendered Flash movie (*.swf) that I converted to its original format (*.fla) with its associated resources like Action - Button - Font - Frame - Image - Shape - Sprite using a Flash decompiler software.

what is the right way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating The Flash From Scratch using the wanted information in the desired langauage can solve that problem.**